# Proof of first Sylow theorem

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

helle fox,

So, there is a proof of the first Sylow theorem using the following lemma:

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $S$ a $p$-Sylow of $G$, so there exist an element $g$ of $G$ such that $gSg^{-1}\cap H$ is a $p$-Sylow of $H$.

Here is the proof of the lemma:
Consider the action of $G$ on the quotient set $(G/S)_{g}$ by multiplication, so the stabliliser of an element $gS$ of $(G/S)_{g}$ is $gSg^{-1}$.

Then we take the restriction of the action of $G$ on $(G/S)_{g}$, namely:$$H\times (G/S)_{g}\mapsto (G/S)_{g}$$
the stabliliser of an element gS of $(G/S)_{g}$ by this new action is $gSg^{-1}\cap H$, and they say this is a $p$-group of $G$.

My question is: Why $gSg^{-1}\cap H$ is a $p$-group of $H$, since $gSg^{-1}\cap H$ can be the $\{1\}$.

Notice: a p-group is a group of order $p^{\alpha}$, whereh $\alpha$ is an integer $\geq 1$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As the lemma is stated, $p$ needs not divide the order of $H$, and thus it's entirely possible that $\lvert gSg^{-1}\cap H\rvert=1$.

Comment: Thank you Saucy o'Path, yes this is exactley my problem, so This lemma is wrong!!.

Comment: No the lemma is not wrong. Your definition of $p$-group is wrong. A $p$-group is a group in which the order of all elements is a power of $p$, and $1=p^0$ is a power of $P$, so the trivial group is a $p$-group for all primes $p$.

Comment: Thank you Derek Holt for your ansewr, if we suppose that the trivial group $\{1\}$ it is a p-groupe, then  it's center Z($=\{1\}$) it's not trivial (it's a classic theorem of p-group), (Contradiction with the theorem)

Comment: Every statement of this result that I have found says that the center of a nontrivial finite $p$-group is nontrivial. See for example the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-group). Note also that infinite $p$-groups can have trivial center.

Comment: Thank you Derek Holt for your answer, so it seems to me that there is two definition of p-groupe, some says the a p-group is a group of order $p^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$, and in the other hands, some says that a  p-group is a group of order $p^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{N^*}$, So the proof work with the first definition, thanks a lot for your help.